# Why Android resource linking failed in Flutter APK build with flutter_pdfview package

Tags: flutter

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':flutter_pdfview:verifyReleaseResources'.

```
A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.VerifyLibraryResourcesTask$Action
Android resource linking failed
ERROR:/Users/pawan/Documents/GitHub/flutter_project/build/flutter_pdfview/intermediates/merged_res/release/values/values.xml:132: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/lStar not found.
```

I would like to mention that I am using version 0.4.1 of the flutter_cached_pdfview package, which depends on the flutter_pdfview package. Interestingly, this issue only occurs when I run flutter build apk and not when I use flutter build appbundle or flutter run on the emulator. Furthermore, running flutter doctor -v does not report any issues.

I tried

```
flutter upgrade
flutter clean
flutter pub get
```

but it's not resolve my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to manage version of `flutter_pdfview` as mentioned in issue section of library . Kindly visit below mentioned link and manage as shown

https://github.com/binSaed/flutter_cached_pdfview/issues/95#issuecomment-1510450655